# Error: Using std::forward in initialize-lists

Tags: c++, forwarding-reference

I create a class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person {
 public:
  template<typename T>
  Person(T&& _name) :
    m_name(std::forward<T>(_name)) {
    }
 private:
  std::string m_name;
};
```

and invoke it:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  Person p("Nancy");
  return 0;
}
```

But the compiler throw a error and lots of message:

```
t.cc:8:5: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
    m_name(std::forward<T>(_name)) {
    ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Type of `_name` is universal reference, and I perfectly forward `_name` to `m_name`.

As I know,

if  `_name` is l-value, type of  `_name` will be inferred as `std::string&`,

if  `_name` is r-value, type of  `_name` will be inferred as`std::string&&`,

I initialize `Person` with "Nancy" which is r-value, so it should work fine as I known.

I feel confused.

Comment: `#include <utility>` missing

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7e09e8438baaaa7).

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Hi @ NutCracke: After I add `#include <utility>`, it work fine. My compiler is clang-8. Do you tell me why work fine after I add  `#include <utility>`, please write it in the answer, thanks :)

Comment: @curlywei i added an answer. please let me know if you need further explanation or accept is as correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::forward` function is defined in `utility` header so you are missing your include statement:

```
#include <utility>
```

Check the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).